# Extending body classes in front- and backend

Tags: templates, css, filters

I want to extend both body classes for the front-end as well as for the admin area. I have seen some snippets floating around, which led me to the following

```
add_filter('body_class','add_custom_body_classes');
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'add_custom_body_classes');
```

Now it seems to me, that I do have to do a type check like the following, because in the case of the backend extension the variable is a string and not an array.

```
function add_custom_body_classes($classes) {
    $someClassA = 'someText';
    $someClassB = 'someText';

    if (is_array($classes)) {
        $classes[] = $someClassA;
        $classes[] = $someClassB;
    }
    else {
        $classes .= ' ' . $someClassA;
        $classes .= ' ' . $someClassB;
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Is this correct or what is it I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet adds the following classes to the body tag on the front end,

```
someText
someText
```

Your snippet adds the following classes to the body tag on the back end,

```
someClassA
someClassB
```

If that is you intended result, then yes that works and is correct.

You could also do,

```
function add_custom_body_classes($classes) {

    $someClassA = 'someText';
    $someClassB = 'someText';

    if (is_array($classes)) {
        $classes[] = $someClassA;
        $classes[] = $someClassB;
    }
    elseif (is_admin()) {
        $classes .= ' ' . someClassA;
        $classes .= ' ' . someClassB;
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class','add_custom_body_classes');
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'add_custom_body_classes');
```

By using `is_admin` conditional statement to make sure you are on the admin page before adding specific classes.

If none of the above is correct, and you want the same classes (`someText`) to appear on both front and back end, then you need to modify...

```
$classes .= ' ' . someClassA;
$classes .= ' ' . someClassB;
```

To show,

```
$classes .= ' ' . $someClassA;
$classes .= ' ' . $someClassB;
```

As you were missing `$` in your variable names.

Assuming you want the same classes on front and back ends you can also do an array to string conversion like,

```
function add_custom_body_classes($classes) {

$classes = array('classA', 'classB', 'classC');
$string  = implode($classes, ' ');

    if (!is_admin() && is_array($classes)) {
        return $classes;
    }
    elseif (is_admin()) {
        return $string;
    }
}

add_filter('body_class','add_custom_body_classes');
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'add_custom_body_classes');
```

Comment: Thanks for your confimation and your idea to use `implode`! The missing "$" was by accident and I've corrected it. Lastly: Do you have any idea, why the classes variable isn't of the same type in these two callbacks?

Comment: No problem and yes, poor design choice/consistency. You get that from time to time when dealing with core. Look at: [`wp-includes/post-template.php`](http://bit.ly/PBaQoC) & [`wp-admin/admin-header.php`](http://bit.ly/Ug861N) one is concatenating a rather simple set strings (`admin-header.php`) while the other is iterating over a more complex array which deals with template files in your theme. Concatenating strings doesn't make sense in that case. Admittedly it could do with some standardization. If you want, you could always write a patch and submit it to core http://core.trac.wordpress.org